# vim ex mode write to stdout

Tags: ex-mode

I am trying to output the contents of a file opened in vim ex mode to stdout.

```
vi -es +'%write !tee' +'q' ./testfile
```

Unfortunately, it does not write anything, although if I open the file in ex mode, like this:

```
vi -e ./testfile
```

and issue the same command:

```
:%write !tee
```

then the file contents are shown.

Of course, there are other vi commands I would issue before writing to stdout but first I would like to make this one work.

Note: I also tried the `print` and `list` commands, however, they replace tabs (and I want to keep them as they are in the file).

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V. Though they're using `%p` there, so I think it has the shortcoming that tabs won't work as you mentioned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hack but if a direct solution can't be found perhaps it will do (I have an idea of how to do it purely with vim but need to try it later).

Try the *print* command `:[range][p]rint [flags]` with `l` as a flag. This will replace tabs with `^I` (two characters). Then use `sed` to replace with actual tabs.

For example, to output an entire file:

```
 vim -e -s -c'%p l|q!' foo.txt | sed 's/^I/\t/g'
```

(The `-s` (silent mode) flag keeps the screen from jumping.)

**Update:** Okay, I'm not seeing any simple way to do this. Almost everything strips the tabs. Best I can come up with is still hacky but at least it's pure vim. It'll only work with *nix systems with the special file `/dev/stdout`.

You need a custom function. One approach is to put it in a file and source it. Here's the function:

```
func! DumpToStdout()
    redi! > /dev/stdout
    for line in getline(1, '$')
        echo line
    endfor
    redi END
endfunc
```

If I put it in, say, `dump.vim` then the `vim`/`ex` command is

```
vim -e -S dump.vim -s -c 'call DumpToStdout()' -c 'q!' foo.txt
```

(Actually, you could probably cram the function contents into the command line and avoid the need for the extra file but...yuck.)

Comment: I wonder if you could use vis instead of sed for the first attempt?

Comment: vis? What is that?

Comment: Perhaps I meant unvis; vis and unvis are a pair of programs designed around cat -v; the first visualizes unprintables in a text stream, while the second restores the actual unprintables.

Comment: I'm know linux command line quite well and know about cat's -v and -t/-T but I don't recall hearing about vis/unvis. Is it gnu or perhaps a different user land flavor?

Comment: I only just read about them (i think in fred brooks’ no silver bullet, but maybe not—certainly a paper/essay on good design). I found them happily on my mac, but im not sure if they came from coreutils or moreutils or what. Ill look later.

Comment: Ok, after looking, they appear to possibly be BSD-isms. Examples: `printf 'a\tb c\n' | vis -w` gives `a\011b\040c\012`; `printf 'a\tb c\n' | vis -wc` gives `a\tb\sc\n`. `vis | unvis` is basically `cat` with no arguments, and `unvis` correctly gives the same as `printf 'a\tb c\n'` when the examples are piped into it. So if you can match one of the `vis` formats, you can use `unvis` to undo it

Comment: Thanks, your proposed 'yucky' answer, `vi -es +"redir! > /dev/stdout | for line in getline( 1, '$' ) | echo line | endfor | redir END" +"quit" ./testfile` works (I can insert more commands after `-es`, so it's useful for any text editing / pattern searching purpose).

Comment: @z32a7ul Glad it works for you, yucky or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `/dev/stdout` is available on your system, you can try

```
vi -es +'%write! /dev/stdout' +'q' ./testfile
```

On many modern Linux systems, `/dev/stdout` is a symlink to file descriptor 1 of the current process (`/proc/self/fd/1`, aka stdout). If you are on Linux but don't have `/dev/stdout`, then there is still a possibility that this will work:

```
vi -es +'%write! /proc/self/fd/1' +'q' ./testfile
```

Comment: This one works, too, thanks.